# d3js V6, how to use more than one left axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, yaxis

My goal its a chart with multiple Y axis.Example below
[image: multi Y axis chart]

Than I try call d3.axisLeft().scale() for the second Y axis, axis is drawing but not scaled

```
var yscaleLvl = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(chartData, function (d) { return (d.lvlData*1.2) /10.0; } )] )
            .range([height / 2, 0]);

        var yscaleVolume = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(chartData, function (d) { return (d.volumeData * 1.2) / 10.0; })])
            .range([height / 2, 0]);
var y_axisLvl = d3.axisLeft().scale(yscaleLvl);
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(50, 10)")
            .attr("stroke-width", 3.0)
            .call(y_axisLvl);

        
        var y_axisVolume = d3.axisLeft().scale(yscaleVolume);
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(15, 10)")
            .attr("stroke-width", 3.0)
            .call(y_axisVolume);
```

It's possible do in the direct way, or need more trickiest way ?

Answer (score 1):

The way you posted is exactly how you add more than one axis.

```js
    const yScaleA = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,1]).range([10,190])
    const yScaleB = d3.scaleLinear().domain([10,100]).range([10,190])
    
    const yAxisA = d3.axisLeft(yScaleA)
    const yAxisB = d3.axisLeft(yScaleB)
    
    const svg = d3.select('svg')
    
    svg.append('g').attr('transform','translate(100,0)').call(yAxisA)
    svg.append('g').attr('transform','translate(50,0)').call(yAxisB)
```

Here is a [minimal working example](https://codepen.io/rodrigodivino/pen/QWKzxqE) to demonstrate.

If you didn't achieve this result, then there is a bug somewhere else in the application.